# ActionMailer standalone @Html

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, email, actionmailer.net

Hi I'm trying to use actionmailer standalone in a WCF service and everything works according to plan when it comes to substituting data using Model.XXX.

The problem starts when I try parsing templates using @Html

I receive : Unable to compile template. The name 'Html' does not exist in the current context

example template the works:

Hello **@Model.Name**

template failing

Hello **@Model.Name** 
    @Html.CheckBox("test")

So how can HtmlHelpers be used with actionmailer in a standalone scenario?

Comment: Press F12 on the `Model` property to see the underlying razor object of your webpage. There will or will not be the `Html` property.

Comment: The problem is not the Model object the variable substitutions are ok , but HTML helpers doesn't appear to be recognized the problem starts when @Html is included and the view gets an error Unable to compile template. The name 'Html' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure you have the `web.config` file inside your Views folder which helps the razor engine to have some extensions you might use:

```xml
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```